# How to set JAVA_HOME for multiple Tomcat instances?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have 2 Java Web Projects. One runs on JDK 1.5 and the other runs on JDK 1.6. I want to run both of them on the same computer, but the JAVA_HOME environment variable can only have one value. I want to set JAVA_HOME for each Tomcat server.

Comment: Related question (for Linux): http://askubuntu.com/questions/154953/specify-jdk-for-tomcat7

Answer (score 47):

place a setenv.sh in the the bin directory with

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_43/
JRE_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_43/jre
```

or an other version your running.

Comment: No need to add `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME`. _If both JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME are specified, JRE_HOME is used._
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt

Answer (score 20):

One thing that you could do would be to modify the catalina.sh (Unix based) or the catalina.bat (windows based).

Within each of the scripts you can set certain variables which only processes created under the shell will inherit. So for catalina.sh, use the following line:

```
export JAVA_HOME="intented java home"
```

And for windows use

```
set JAVA_HOME="intented java home"
```

Comment: Isn't the windows version supposed to differ from the unix version?  I'm no batch guy, but I thought it was `set`, or am I dating myself?

Comment: I'm using Windows XP and I have added line "export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12" at the beginning of file Tomcat/bin/catalina.bat
But Tomcat can not start
Herr is a part of my file

rem Guess CATALINA_HOME if not defined
export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12"
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xmx512m
set CURRENT_DIR=%cd%
if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome
set CATALINA_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat" goto okHome

Comment: Ah. Evil use of the copy paste! I did not mean to put export for the windows version. Ry4an was correct in that set is the correct command. Updating the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have solved my poblem
We have to use set command and vaule of JAVA_HOME with be a String without " character (set JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12 )

Comment: Documnetation says that it should be done in **setenv**, not in **catalina**
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt

Answer (score 14):

If you are a **Windows** user, put the content below in a **setenv.bat** file that you must create in Tomcat **bin** directory.

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.x
```

If you are a **Linux** user, put the content below in a **setenv.sh** file that you must create in Tomcat **bin** directory.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.x
```

Answer (score 8):

Also, note that there shouldn't be any space after `=`:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add setenv.sh in the the bin directory with:

> export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")

and it will dynamically change when you update your packages.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a best practice (You may be have many Tomcat instance in same computer, you want per Tomcat instance use other Java Runtime Environment):

[image]

[image]

This is manual inside file: `catalina.sh`

```
#   JRE_HOME        Must point at your Java Runtime installation.
#                   Defaults to JAVA_HOME if empty. If JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME
#                   are both set, JRE_HOME is used.
```

Comment: good solution. thanks @Raphaël Colantonio

Answer (score 3):

In UNIX I had this problem, I edited `catalina.sh` manually and entered

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24
echo "Using JAVA_HOME:       $JAVA_HOME"
```

as the first 2 lines. I tried setting the `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/profile` but it did not help.

This worked finally.

Answer (score 2):

Linux based Tomcat6 should have **/etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf**

```
# System-wide configuration file for tomcat6 services
# This will be sourced by tomcat6 and any secondary service
# Values will be overridden by service-specific configuration
# files in /etc/sysconfig
#
# Use this one to change default values for all services
# Change the service specific ones to affect only one service
# (see, for instance, /etc/sysconfig/tomcat6)
#

# Where your java installation lives
#JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0"

# Where your tomcat installation lives
CATALINA_BASE="/usr/share/tomcat6"
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem my OS is windows 8 and I am using Tomcat 8,
I just edited the ***setclasspath.bat*** file in bin folder and set JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME
like this...

> @echo off
>   ...
>   ...
>   set "JRE_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre8"
>   set "JAVA_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.7.0_03"
>   ...
>   ...

and it works fine for me now......

Answer (score 2):

For Debian distro we can override the setting via defaults

```
/etc/default/tomcat6
```

Set the `JAVA_HOME` pointing to the java version you want.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note...

If you add that code to setclasspath.bat or setclasspath.sh, it will actually be used by all of Tomcat's scripts you could run, rather than just Catalina.

The method for setting the variable is as the other's have described.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need add in startup.sh or startup.bat the `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19`

[image]

After check...

[image]