# can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8000

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

I recently uninstalled an old version of java and reinstalled java to C:\Program Files\Java\jre7, but now i am getting a `can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8000` from my apache tomcat server held in C:\Program Files\Apache Group.

Any ideas on what is causing this error?

Comment: is there a program listening on port 8000? check the settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps Apache is pointing to the old installation you chose in the setup wizard. If you think the re-installation is causing the problem, I'd suggest trying to change the JAVA_HOME environment variable. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698913/how-to-set-java-home-in-tomcat-config) may help.

Comment: It's an environment variable, not a file. Open your terminal and run the proper command. Google "set JAVA_HOME <your OS>". Regardless of why your server isn't behaving properly, it's never a bad idea to set JAVA_HOME.