# how do i find where JAVA_OPTS data is stored?

Tags: java, linux

A CentOS 7 server has Java 7 and tomcat 8 installed.  I need to set the permgen space, but typing `printenv` on the command line does not include `JAVA_OPTS` in the list of environmental variables.  I typed `ps` to get the list of running processes, and then I typed `jmap -heap <pid>` with the pid from the running java process, which listed values for `MaxPermSize` and `PermSize` among other values.

**How do I set new values for these properties in a way that will persist when the system is rebooted, etc.?**  I hesitate to just create a `JAVA_OPTS` variable if the server in question has another place where it stores these persistent values.

---

**EDIT:**

---

As per @ChrisRobak's suggestion, I went searching for tomcat conf files.  There is no `/etc/tomcat` directory, but `/etc` has directories called `/etc/java`, `/etc/.java`, `/etc/jvm`, and `/etc/jvm-common`.  Also, the tomcat conf is as follows:

```
[root@myserver tomcat]# cd /opt/tomcat/conf
[root@myserver conf]# ls -al
total 280
drwxrwx---.  3 root root   4096 Oct 30 20:02 .
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root   4096 Oct 30 20:58 ..
drwxrwx---.  7 root root   4096 Oct 30 21:00 Catalina
-rwxrwx---.  1 root root  12624 Nov  2  2014 catalina.policy
-rwxrwx---.  1 root root   6560 Nov  2  2014 catalina.properties
-rwxrwx---.  1 root root   1852 Jan  2  2015 context.xml
-rwxrwx---.  1 root root   3451 Nov  2  2014 logging.properties
-rwxr-x---   1 root root   5018 Oct 30 21:52 server.xml
-rwxrwx---.  1 root root   1783 Nov  2  2014 tomcat-users.xml
-rwxrwx---.  1 root root   1888 Nov  2  2014 tomcat-users.xsd
-rwxrwx---.  1 root root 168082 Nov  2  2014 web.xml
[root@myserver conf]#
```

Which file should I look in?

Alternatively, is there a command line way of setting the Java options which will not only be persistent, but also not cause side effects due to conflicts with config files?  **I would just create a `JAVA_OPTS` variable if I thought the rest of the server would go to the `JAVA_OPTS` as the default.**

---

**ANSWER?**

---

When none of the config files and scripts seemed to have JAVA_OPTS set, I finally just decided to type the following in the CENTOS 7 terminal:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

The result is that the MaxPermSize has been reset.  If anyone else has a specific answer to CentOS 7 that is better than this, please alert me.

Comment: IIRC, Java8 does not use PermGen.

Comment: @Jayan That was a typo.  It is Java 7.  I updated my OP and added edit after another user's suggestion.  Do you have other ideas?

Comment: Alright: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698913/how-to-set-java-home-for-multiple-tomcat-instances

Comment: @Jayan There is no `tomcat.conf` on the computer.  When I created `/opt/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh` and restarted tomcat, the `MaxPermSize` was not changed, so I deleted it.  I will open up `catalina.sh` now and start reviewing it, but I am just guessing.

Comment: @Jayan `JAVA_OPTS` is not set in my `catalina.sh`, though it is called by a few `eval` commands in that file.  I hesitate to edit `catalina.sh because there is so much that could go wrong.  I typed `grep "JAVA_OPTS`, but that command has not returned anything after a long time and perhaps might never return anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can persist those in

```
/etc/tomcat8/tomcat8.conf
```

or a similar variant, the server i had access to was `/etc/tomcat5/tomcat5.conf` but i don't know about your version in particular