# Tomcat using wrong Java version

Tags: java, tomcat

On the same server I need to run Java 6 and Java 8. The Tomcat web app should use Java 6, and I have set my JAVA_HOME environment variable to the path to Java 6.

However my web app which requires Java 6 is not running. The Catalina log under C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\logs\catalina.2016-10-18.log is showing:

INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_101-b13

How can I tell Tomcat to use version 6?

your help is appreciated,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set JAVA\_HOME for multiple Tomcat instances?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698913/how-to-set-java-home-for-multiple-tomcat-instances)

Comment: Thanks, I created a setenv.bat containing set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45, however Tomcat is still looking for version 8 as shown in the original post. Is there anything else besides the bat file? thx

Comment: Are you running Tomcat as a service? If so, the Java version in effect when the service was created is being used. Remove and re-add the service.

Comment: thanks a lot Andreas, your advice pointed me in the right direction. I launched Tomcat7w.exe from the bin directory, and in the Java tab I replaced C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\server\jvm.dll with C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll and I restarted the Tomcat service. This resolved the issue. thanks!

Comment: I solved my problem:
" the Java version in effect when the service was created is being used. Remove and re-add the service"

thanks!